# How would i orderBy my query based on values from a diffrent tabel that it is in a relationship with

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have 2 tabels one being vehicles and another being road tax.

my 'vehicles' tabel has an id & registration field which is in relationship with my 'road tax' tabel which has id, vehicle_id, vaild from & an expires field. i have a one to many relationship as my vehicles will have had many years history of when i taxed them

i need the most simple way to list all my vehicles in order of which will need to be re-taxed first.

the closest i have is getting my vehicles to list when the tax is due to expire. i am really strugling to get them in the order i need. i have a basic understanding of php and mysql so hoping someone can shine a light on where i need to focus. i thought i could either just orderBy the expires colum, just like how i can successfully orderBy registration. is this because my expires field originate from a realtionship table?

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Road_tax;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */

    public function Index()
    {
        $road_taxes = Vehicle::with('latest_Road_Tax')->get()

        return view('dashboard.index', compact('road_taxes'));
    }
}
```

Vehicle Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{

    public function Road_taxes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Road_tax::class);
    }

    public function latest_Road_Tax()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Road_tax::class)->latest("expires");
    }
    
}
```

View

```
 @foreach($road_taxes as $road_tax) 
    <div class="dashboard-item-title">
      <h6 style="font-weight:600; margin-bottom:0px;">{{$road_tax->registration}}</h6>

      <span class="dashboard-item-body" style="margin-top:-10px;">
        <small style="font-weight:300; color:grey;">Tax expires for this vehicle on</small>
        <small style="font-weight:300"> | {{$road_tax->latest_Road_Tax->expires}}</small>
      </span>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that. You can just `join` `road_tax` table and order the query by ascending `expires` field. Or you can add relationship `belongsTo` to `Road_tax` class and then query just `Road_tax` class so later you can access `Vehicle` data through the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is a `with()` method and pass as a query builder.

So basically you only need 1 relationship `vehicle->hasMany(Road_tax::class)`

Your model should be:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{

    public function road_taxes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Road_tax::class);
    }
    
}
```

So if you want every vehicle to list their latest road tax

You can query this using `with()`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */

    public function Index()
    {
        $road_taxes = Vehicle::with([
            'road_taxes' => function ($query) {
                $query->lastest()->limit(1);
            }
        ])->get();

        return view('dashboard.index', compact('road_taxes'));
    }
}
```

This method will list 1 road taxes associated to the vehicle

## EDITED

This is the where you only get the vehicle with road road taxes

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */

    public function Index()
    {
        $road_taxes = Vehicle::with([
            'road_taxes' => function ($query) {
                $query->lastest()->limit(1);
            }
        ])->has('road_taxes')->get();

        return view('dashboard.index', compact('road_taxes'));
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to only show the latest road tax agaist what ever vehicle has it. then it list my other vehicles with no road tax infomation. am guessing this is due to it not being the latest tax info

Comment: I edited my answer. now you only get the vehicles with a corresponding road taxes